# Remove WooCommerce messages from account content

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to remove all messages from the WooCommerce account with the following code line:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
```

Sadly, the wrapper for messages is still there:

```
<div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper">lol</div>
```

I've added a `lol` to the function that displays the wrapper and it's the correct function I'm trying to remove. No idea why it's not working...

Comment: you can add css to hide it.. would that be a problem?

Comment: As @Reigel Advise, you may remove it through css 
```. woocommerce-notices-wrapper {display: none}

Comment: Yes thats a problem because I need to remove this function that catches messages from WooCommerce and I want to display them within a different location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your active theme uses the default woocommerce templates and hooks for myaccount pages, then add the follows code snippet to achieve the above -

```
function modify_wc_hooks() {
    // remove all wc my account's notices wrapper
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 5 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_lost_password_form', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
    remove_action( 'before_woocommerce_pay', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_reset_password_form', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'modify_wc_hooks', 99 );
```

Codes goes to your active theme's functions.php